# Modify Update with Inner Join to avoid error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a parent/child relationship with the following statement:

```
    UPDATE (SELECT F2.FOLDERRSN NEW, F1.PARENTRSN OLD 
      FROM AMANDA.FOLDER F1
      INNER JOIN AMANDA.FOLDER F2 ON F1.PARENTRSN = F2.CONVERSIONRSN
      WHERE F1.FOLDERRSN BETWEEN 213010 AND 217773
      AND F2.FOLDERTYPE = 'ESC') T
    SET T.OLD = T.NEW
```

The select statement works and shows the two values that I expect, but in conjunction with the update I receive the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Can anyone help me out with another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE AMANDA.FOLDER F1
SET F1.PARENTRSN = (
   SELECT F2.FOLDERRSN
   FROM AMANDA.FOLDER F2
   WHERE F1.PARENTRSN = F2.CONVERSIONRSN
     AND F2.FOLDERTYPE = 'ESC'
)
WHERE F1.FOLDERRSN BETWEEN 213010 AND 217773
```

but most likely the above query will throw the error:
 `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`,
because of the same reason as your query gives  ORA-01779

Comment: It worked! No errors were given when compiled! I appreciate your help!!